# React Native Axios get method undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-native

I'm getting this error when I try to use get method in Axios:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_axios.axios.get')

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably importing wrong by trying to import `axios` as an object.

Wrong:

```
import { axios } from 'axios';
```

Right:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more of your code. And this code works for me:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = [Input Your Base URL Here];

axios.get('/').then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

check your `package.json` also, and run `npm install` if you haven't.

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
...
```